# NSRunAlertPanel not working in Tiger, though it works on Leopard and Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, nsrunalertpanel

I'm currently using `NSRunAlertPanel` to display a dialog.

It works perfectly in Leopard and Snow Leopard. In Tiger, it also works except for the icon.

In Leopard and Snow Leopard, the icon I used for the App is displayed on the left side of the strings. This is the expected behavior.

However, in Tiger, there is a big margin on the left side of the strings, the icon is missing but the gap for the icon is there.

Here's how i used the code:

```
NSRunAlertPanel(@"My Application", @"My Application's string contents", @"OK", nil, nil);
```

I really need to know why this happens. I did not add any code for the icon to appear in leopard and snow, but it's there.

Comment: Tidied up the code sample to show NSStrings instead of c strings as per the questioner's comment.

Comment: `NSRunAlertPanel()` has been long been overtaken by `NSAlert`. How about trying with that?

Answer (score 1):

The `NSRunAlertPanel` function is available starting from Mac OS X 10.0. The only problem I can see in your code is that you are passing C strings to the function where `NSString` objects are expected.

Comment: Sorry, its supposed to be:
NSRunAlertPanel(@"My Application", @"My Application's string contents", @"OK", nil, nil);

I just forgot to write the "@" in the thread.

Thanks.